# Removing data from seurat object

Tags: r, dataframe, seurat

I have single cell sequencing data stored in a seurat object. I tried different clustering resolutions on it using:

```
sunion <- ScaleData(sunion, verbose = FALSE)
sunion <- RunPCA(sunion, npcs = 50, verbose = FALSE)
sunion <- RunUMAP(sunion, reduction = "pca", dims = 1:50)
sunion <- FindNeighbors(sunion, reduction = "pca", dims = 1:50)
sunion <- FindClusters(sunion, resolution = 0.5)
```

Just now I noticed that I have total of 9 different resolutions of clusterings saved in the seurat object and that has inflated the file size. I tried to remove unnecessary resolutions like this

```
data<-sunion@meta.data[,c(1:26,29,30,31,34,35,41)]
sunion<-data
```

but this only saved the meta.data from seurat object and the object turned into a dataframe. How do I remove the unnecessary data from my object?

Edit: Additional info: The data is stored in sunion@meta.data$integrated_snn_res.XXX

Comment: have you tried `subset`?

Comment: @Roman I tried to take negative subset:

data<-sunion@meta.data[,-c(1:26,29,30,31,34,35,41)]
colnames(data)
sunnion<-subset(sunion, subset = meta.data[,-("data")])
This gave me an error though.
Not sure how to formulate subset when I want to keep everything else, including stuff outside the metadata, but remove these few rows of metadata.

Comment: Since you provided no example data I can only assume that you need a rowwise condition, not one on columns!? With your approach you are filtering out columns. Subset is for rows

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
    sunion@meta.data$integrated_snn_res.XXX <- NULL
```

You can do it for all the resolutions you don't need anymore and want to remove, each time changing .XXX to the appropriate value.